# Type of a C++ string literal

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012, c++11, types

Out of curiosity, I'm wondering what the real underlying type of a C++ string literal is.

Depending on what I observe, I get different results.

A typeid test like the following:

```
std::cout << typeid("test").name() << std::endl;
```

shows me `char const[5]`.

Trying to assign a string literal to an incompatible type like so (to see the given error):

```
wchar_t* s = "hello";
```

I get `a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "wchar_t *"` from VS12's IntelliSense.

But I don't see how it could be `const char *` as the following line is accepted by VS12:

```
char* s = "Hello";
```

I have read that this was allowed in pre-C++11 standards as it was for retro-compatibility with C, although modification of `s` would result in Undefined Behavior. I assume that this is simply VS12 having not yet implemented all of the C++11 standard and that this line would normally result in an error.

Reading the C99 standard ([from here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 6.4.5.5) suggests that it should be an array:

> The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize **an array** of static storage duration and length just
>   sufﬁcient to contain the sequence.

So, **what is the type underneath a C++ string literal?**

Thank you very much for your precious time.

Comment: VS12 speaks some strange dialect that is similar, but not identical to, C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of a string literal is indeed `const char[SIZE]` where `SIZE` is the length of the string plus the null terminating character.

The fact that you're sometimes seeing `const char*` is because of the usual array-to-pointer decay.

> But I don't see how it could be `const char *` as the following line is accepted by VS12:
>   `char* s = "Hello";`

This was correct behaviour in C++03 (as an exception to the usual const-correctness rules) but it has been deprecated since. A C++11 compliant compiler should not accept that code.

Comment: The "usual array-to-pointer decay" does not occur in all contexts. In C, it occurs unless the array expression is the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`, or is a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array (sub)object. C++ has more exceptions.

Comment: The correct term is the _Array-to-pointer Conversion_, which is a _Standard Conversion_ documented in clause 4 of the latest C++ standard.  Roughly speaking, standard conversions may be applied implicitly to expressions by the compiler in certain contexts.

Answer (score 5):

The type of a string literal is `char const[N]` where `N` is the number of characters including the terminating null character. Although this type does **not** convert to `char*`, the C++ standard includes a clause allowing assignments of string literal to `char*`. This clause was added to support compatibility especially for C code which didn't have `const` back then.

The relevant clause for the type in the standard is 2.14.5 [lex.string] paragraph 8:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

Comment: Note that this exceptional clause is now deprecated, and trying to assign a string literal to a `char*` should yield a compile-time error.

Comment: @syam - "deprecated" means that it is still legal, but could go away in the future. The conversion of a string literal to a `char*` was deprecated in C++03; it became invalid in C++11. However, the language definition does not require a "compile-time error". For violations of diagnosable constraints, the only requirement is that the compiler issue a diagnostic; having done that, it is free to continue compiling the code. That's the hook for implementation-specific extensions. There is only one situation that requires a compiler to refuse to compile code: a `#error` directive.

Answer (score -1):

First off, the type of a C++ string literal is an array of *n* `const char`.  Secondly, if you want to initialise a wchar_t with a string literal you have to code:

```
wchar_t* s = L"hello"
```

Comment: This was not meant to be valid code, only a test to see the given error. The standard really makes it sound like it should be an array, though.

Comment: No, a string literal is not a `const char*` but a `const char[SIZE]` as explained in other answers. -1

Comment: Then explain why `sizeof "hello, world"` yields 13.

Comment: @Keith: you get a closing 0 for free when initializing a string constant.

Comment: @Jongware I know that. I'm asking Paul Evans to explain why it's not the same as `sizeof (const char*)`. (And yes, I know that too.)

Comment: @syam Yes, you are right, I was wrong. C++03 2.13.4 states: An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char”.  Have amended answer accordingly.

Comment: @PaulEvans "*Have amended answer accordingly.*" => Downvote removed. ;)