# Why in C++ when i concat a string with '+' like it don't concat but remove first char of the string

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, cout

i was learning C++ after 6-7 years of java and i have encouter a problem, in this snippet that instead of "concat" it's just remove the n character as the input has been given..

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int id;
    std::cin >> id;
    std::cout << "Hello world!" + id << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output isn't

```
Hello world!*input*
```

but instead it's subtract to "hello world" the n character given in the input. if i give 8 the output will be rld!.
If someone could explain this.. i will glad to hear! =)

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic

Comment: so..? please explain XD =)

Comment: You can't learn a language by guesswork - get a decent book and start studying.

Comment: You arbitrarily switched from `<<` to `+`. If you can explain why you did that, you can explain why it's a problem. If you can't, you shouldn't have done. Book time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how pointer arithmetics work in C/C++.

Basically, `"Hello world!"` is just a `const char*` and its `+` operator works on it like a pointer. Which means that, for example, if you add `3` to it, then instead of pointing to the beginning of `"Hello world"` it will point to 3 characters after the beginning. If you print that, you get `llo world`.
So you're not doing a string concatenation there.

If you just want to print the stuff, you can use `operator <<` and do something like this instead:

```
std::cout << "Hello world!" << id << std::endl;
```

If you need a string that actually works like a string, consider using `std::string` from the standard library or if you use something like Qt, you can use `QString`.

With a modern compiler (that supports C++11), you can use `std::to_string` to create a string from an `int`, and then you can do it like this:

```
std::string s = "Hello world!";
int i;
std::cin >> i;
s += std::to_string(i);
std::cout << s;
```

If you consider getting seriously into C++ app development, consider using a library like Qt or boost, which make your work just that much easier, although knowing the standard library well is also a good thing. :)

Comment: and to, concat a string i should use some methods.. right?

Comment: wooow.. i fell like an idiot.. XD

thanx very much =)

Comment: that, or simply don't use bare string literals (`"abc"`) but `std::string`s. They are way more similar to Java strings.

Comment: @AndreaBori don't feel bad, it's just a different language than what you're used to!

Comment: i know that C++ have to do basically.. everything and java just do a line..

Comment: @AndreaBori If you know a proper C++ framework like Qt, then it's not so much worse than Java. :)

Comment: it's like visual basic..?

Comment: Take a look: http://qt.io

Answer (score 2):

"Hello world!" is, in C (which C++ is based on), of type const char[] which then gets treated as a const char* when you try to use pointer arithmetic. In other words it's a memory address pointing to (say) the location OxDEAD0000 which contains the characters "Hello world!" and a null terminator.

```
"Hello world!" + id
```

therefore resolves (if id is 8) to 0xDEAD0008

the stream operator then operates on the contents of this address, which is an offset of 8 characters into "Hello world!" - i.e. "rld!".

Comment: thanx for this, but too much explain.. XD i only need to understood why that works in't that way.. =)

Comment: A [string literal's type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18423201/1889329) is an array, not a pointer. However, an array can decay to a pointer to the first element, e.g. when used in pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `operator<<`

```
std::cout << "Hello world!" << id << std::endl;
```

Or if you have access to C++11 you can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
std::cout << "Hello world!" + std::to_string(id) << std::endl;
```